# Reading mlmodel from Bundle in objective C

Tags: objective-c, coreml, coremltools

I am trying read a .mlmodel file to compile and use it in our library. I am testing the library but I can not read the file and compile it... I don't know exactly why. I am  using these two functions (neither work)

```
-(NSString*) FilePathForResourceName:(NSString*) name  forExtension:(NSString*) extension {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSString* file_path = [bundle pathForResource:name ofType:extension];
    return file_path;
}


-(NSString*) FilePathForMainBundleResourceName:(NSString*) name  forExtension:(NSString*) extension {
    NSBundle *main = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* file_path = [main pathForResource:name ofType:extension];
    return file_path;
}
```

This is the test example where network_path returns always nil:

```
- (void)testShouldAnalyseCorrectlyWithDetectionBicycles {
    NSString* image_path = [self FilePathForResourceName:@"bicycles" forExtension:@"jpg"];
    NSString* labels_path = [self FilePathForResourceName:@"coco_labels_list" forExtension:@"txt"];
    NSString* network_path = [self FilePathForResourceName:@"ssd_mobilenet_feature_extractor" forExtension:@"mlmodel"];
    CoreMLLib* lib = [[CoreMLLib alloc] init:network_path forLabel:labels_path];
    [lib run:image_path];
}
```

I think, it is added correctly the file in the project (for both targets tests and library):

[image]

value parameters in **FilePathForResourceName**

- name -> ssd_mobilenet_feature_extractor
- extension -> mlmodel
- file_path -> nil
- bundle -> NSBundle
  "/Users/joan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/draagu-ios-tensorflow-lib-hglbgbpvrarumdfwwgjoebcuesar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/draagu-ios-tensorflow-libTests.xctest"  0x00007f7f1fc2cb40

Comment: Try `[NSBundle mainBundle]` instead of `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]`.

Comment: If you see, I have the two methods, I tried both...

Comment: Duh - I missed that second one.  Did you try an `NSLog` on `file_path`? Does it point to the correct location?

Comment: I added the values in the question.

Comment: Is it actually an mlmodel object? How did you create it?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans, it is a mlmodel.. I have worked with them correctly. I am doing these changes to permit reading it from a directory and avoid to added directly  in the project

Comment: If the issue is that `file_path` is nil, then the file does not appear to be present in your bundle, or not at that location. I would open your app bundle (under Products) to see what is actually inside it.

Comment: I checked the bundle in Products. It seems that if I added the  .mlmodel as a resource, xcode compiles mlmodel to mlmodelc and this last file is included in the bundle. I would need to verify...